# Adding five Numbers Entered as Strings in Textfields

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

Command

I have five textfields in which numbers are inputed as strings. I need to convert the strings to numbers, add them together and then display the result in a  lavel.

the user enter a value in each  textfield  and calculate with a button

tanks

Comment: Sounds pretty simple.  Start with one text field and go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have To First Add 5 TextField, 1 Label For Output Result, And One Button.
and Make to create that outlet.. like this... in 
Do it in your .h File

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtField5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblForResult;
- (IBAction)AddButtonClicked:(id)sender;
```

the button is IbAction For Clicking Event 
Ann do it from your .m File 
Addbutton Clicked Event.. or your Button Click Event....

```
- (IBAction)AddButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    int val1=[self.txtField1.text intValue];
    int val2=[self.txtField2.text intValue];
    int val3=[self.txtField3.text intValue];
    int val4=[self.txtField4.text intValue];
    int val5=[self.txtField5.text intValue];
    int result=val1+val2+val3+val4+val5;
    self.lblForResult.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",result];
}
```

OR YOU CAND DO LIKE THIS INSTEAD OF DECLARING THE FIVE VARIABLE....

```
- (IBAction)AddButtonClicked:(id)sender {
 int result=[self.txtField1.text intValue]+[self.txtField2.text intValue]+[self.txtField3.text intValue]+[self.txtField4.text intValue]+[self.txtField5.text intValue];
    self.lblForResult.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",result];
}
```

Comment: Sumit Sharma  you are big  :) THANKS

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say but this is basic 101 programming. Short of writing code for you try this

- If you are using storyboard, Create 5 UITextField IBOutlets
- Connect them to your 5 UITextFields in storyboard
- Create a IBAction and connect it to a UIButton
- Upon button press Get the text value of each string and convert it to int / double depending upon precision you need.
- Add all of them together.
- Convert that int/double back to string and display it in a UILabel